# Errors downloading frameworks using dotnet (NuGet)

Tags: .net, nuget, frameworks, command-line-interface

I am fairly new to downloading frameworks outside of Visual Studio.

Attempting to download packages from dotnet and keep running into an issue where it is not asking the right service?

Using Visual Studio Code and trying to use the CLI. However, when I go to download a framework using
`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
I'm not getting the download and instead I'm getting this:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4k4aga.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' into project 'C:\Users\USERNAME\VScode\BlazingPizza\BlazingPizza.csproj'.
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/index.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/page/0.0.1-alpha/3.1.3.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/page/3.1.4/6.0.0-preview.7.21378.4.json
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/page/6.0.0-rc.1.21452.10/8.0.0.json
info :   GET *Link to a github package*FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   NotFound *Link to a github package* 79ms
error: Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://github.com/oriches/faker-cs/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

I believe the last time I tried to download a package was from Github and I must have changed an environmental variable, or something.

This portion doesn't seem like it belongs:
`info :   GET *Link to a github package* info :   NotFound *Link to a github package*id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 79ms error: Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at '*Link to a github package*/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' with following message : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).`

How do I get rid of this? It seems to be trying to find the package at the github location, and since this was the last package I downloaded when using Visual Studio, I think the pointer or something is stuck at that location.

I tried to download a package in the CLI in Visual Studio Code like so:
`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

And instead it failed to "get", 404 errored out based on a different package I downloaded previously.